# Drawing grids filled with random selected colors and connecting them

Tags: color, grids, node-connections

What I'm trying to do is to draw to 4 x 4 grids side-by-side to represent the concept of bootstrap, from statistics.

So, what I would like to do is to draw them and **fill each cell of each grid with a random color chosen from a predefined set of colors**.

After that, I would like to **connect** the grids with an arrow centered on the y middle of them with and the x positioned at the right and left border of them, respectively.

This is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

This is my current approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]

    \begin{scope}
        \draw (0, 0) grid (4, 4);
        \coordinate (input);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm] 
        \draw (0, 0) grid (4, 4);
        \coordinate (output);
    \end{scope}  

    \draw[-latex, thick, red!80] (input) -- (output) node [pos=0.5,above,font=\footnotesize] {output};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I'm far from what I would like:

[image]

How should I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `to` syntax instead of the `--` for connecting the squares. For coloring the squares you can define a list of colors via `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used `tikz`'s `calc` library to get the midpoint of the squares.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{MyRandomColors}{%
    {red}%
    {red!25}%
    {magenta}%
    {magenta!25}%
    {olive}%
    {olive!25}%
    {brown}%
    {brown!10}%
    {violet}%
    {violet!25}%
    {gray}%
    {purple}%
    {yellow}%
    {orange}%
    {orange!25}%
    {cyan}%
    {green}%    
}%

\newcommand*{\GridSize}{4}

\newcommand*{\ColorCells}{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\GridSize} {
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\GridSize} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomColor}{MyRandomColors} 
            \draw [fill=\RandomColor, fill opacity=0.4, draw=none, ultra thick] 
                (\x-1,\y-1) rectangle (\x,\y);
        }%
    }%
}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]

    \begin{scope}[thick]
        \ColorCells
        \draw (0, 0) grid (\GridSize, \GridSize);
        \coordinate (input);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[thick, xshift=7cm] 
        \ColorCells
        \draw (0, 0) grid (\GridSize, \GridSize);
        \coordinate (output);
    \end{scope}  

    \draw[-latex, ultra thick, red!80] 
        ($(input)+(2.5,2.5)$) to[out=0, in=180] 
            node [pos=0.5,sloped, above,font=\footnotesize] {output}
        ($(output)+(1.5,1.5)$) 
            ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, @PeterGrill. I got some errors here, as "! You can't use `\numexpr' in restricted horizontal mode.". Am I missing something?

Comment: @pceccon: Without seeing the actual code I can't guess as to what the problem is. It seems as if your issue is _not_ specifically about drawing a grid with random fill, but with the use of `\numexpr` so I'd suggest you post a new question.  You can link to this in your question if you think it is relevant.

Comment: Ok, but what this should do? I delete this (\numexpr\x-1\relax,\numexpr\y-1\relax) to compile and now I'm getting the grids fulfilled with a single color.

Comment: It seems that if I comment the opacity or set it to 1.0 I get just one color. This is weird, I would like to have each cell with a random color. Couldn't reproduce your code here. :/

Comment: @pceccon: Does the MWE as provided above work for you? I mean just the MWE, nothing else.

Comment: I just copy and past it in a new empty tex file and it didn't work. Then I commented (\numexpr\x-1\relax,\numexpr\y-1\relax) and it compiled, but with opacity. Since I want opacity = 1.0, I set it and now each grid has a single color.

Comment: @pceccon: If the MWE does not compile for you as is then there is a problem with your distribution. Posted a new version -- guess you don't really need to use `\numexpr` in this case.  You should try updating your packages. Add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}` (as in the new MWE in answer) and post the versions of the packages reported in the log file in the question here.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The code uses 7 colors.  Of course, this can be modified (the number and/or the colors) by changing the command `\rcolor` which produces, for each integer in between 1 and 7, one of the colors.  The integer is created randomly when the grid is drawn.

I defined the colors separately, at the beginning.  It is easier to modify them this way.

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, math, arrows.meta}

\xdefinecolor{sR}{RGB}{238, 4, 34}
\xdefinecolor{sO}{RGB}{255, 102, 17}
\xdefinecolor{sY}{RGB}{238, 204, 17}
\xdefinecolor{sW}{RGB}{230, 240, 235}
\xdefinecolor{sC}{RGB}{17, 170, 187}
\xdefinecolor{sB}{RGB}{17, 87, 221}
\definecolor{sV}{RGB}{153, 0, 238} 

\newcommand{\rcolor}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=1 sR%
  \else\ifnum#1=2 sO%
  \else\ifnum#1=3 sY%
  \else\ifnum#1=4 sW%
  \else\ifnum#1=5 sC%
  \else\ifnum#1=6 sB%
  \else\ifnum#1=7 sV%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{%  controls the distance between the two grids
  real \d; \d = 6.;
  int \tmp;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,3}{%
    \foreach \j in {0,...,3}{%
      \tikzmath{\tmp = random(1, 7);}
      \draw[fill=\rcolor{\tmp}!70, shift={(-2, -2)}]
      (\i,\j) rectangle ++(1, 1);
    }
  }
  \foreach \i in {0, 1, 2, 3}{%
    \foreach \j in {0, 1, 2, 3}{%
      \tikzmath{\tmp = random(1, 7);}
      \draw[fill=\rcolor{\tmp}!70, shift={(\d, -2)}]
      (\i, \j) rectangle ++(1, 1);
    }
  }
  \draw[sR!60!black, -{Latex[length=7pt, width=5pt]}, thick]
  (2.2, 0) -- node[pos=.5, above] {output} (\d-.2, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```