# Front Cover for document part 3

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, covers, shadows

This cover page is building from the solution posted in [Front Cover or document part 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289265/front-cover-for-document-part-2/289285?noredirect=1#comment700090_289285).  I am now trying to place a minipage and a logo with a blur shadow on the cover page like this:

[image]

Here is the code that is written so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, shadows, shadows.blur}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{MyRandomColors}{%
    {red}%
    {red!25}%
    {magenta}%
    {magenta!25}%
    {olive}%
    {olive!25}%
    {brown}%
    {brown!10}%
    {violet}%
    {violet!25}%
    {gray}%
    {purple}%
    {yellow}%
    {orange}%
    {orange!25}%
    {cyan}%
    {green}%
}%

\definecolor{titlecolor1}{rgb}{.9,0.40,0.7}

\newcommand*{\GridSize}{20}

%#2-Gridsizex
%#3-Gridsizey
\newcommand*{\ColorCells}[2]{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#1} {
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomColor}{MyRandomColors}
            \draw [draw=olive!45,fill=\RandomColor, fill opacity=0.2, ultra thick]
                ([shift={(\x-1,\y-1)}]current page.south west) rectangle ++(1cm,1cm);
        }%
    }%
}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.8,ultra thick,olive!45]
        \ColorCells{35}{27}
        \coordinate (input);
    \end{scope}

\node[rotate=90, above right,text width=26cm,
node font=\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1] at ($(current page.south east)+(.25,1)$)
{Depression Problems and Active Modeling};

\node[rotate=90, above right,text width=26cm,
node font=\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1] at ($(current page.south east)+(-5.5,21)$)
{(Spring 2016)};

\node[above right,
node font=\fontsize{40}{90}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1!20!black] at ($(current page.south west)+(1,1)$)
{Jimmy Jones Jeremy};

%\tikzoverlay at (-4.37cm,3cm) {
%\begin{tikzpicture} \node [blur shadow]{
%        \includegraphics[scale=.15]{Logo}
%    };



\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}[l]{10cm}
Contributor: Dixie Wang\\
Date: February 15th, 2016\\
Filed: February 15th, 2016
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I would like some help to get the cover to look like the attached image?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular `node` (with all positioning options) can be used for the `logo`, something like:

```
\node[blur shadow, anchor=north west] at 
     ($(current page.north west)+(1,-1)$) 
     {\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image}};
```

will do the work.

And a similar solution can be applied for the `minipage`. In fact you don't need a minipage to define a multiline `node`, just options like `text width` and `align` will help. `text width` will automatically break lines, so in your case it's not needed because you break them with `\\`.

```
\node[blur shadow, text width=11cm, align=left, draw, anchor=south east,     
      fill=white] at ($(current page.south east)+(-6,5)$){ 
          Contributor: Dixie Wang\\
          Date: February 15th, 2016\\
          Filed: February 15th, 2016};
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, shadows, shadows.blur}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{MyRandomColors}{%
    {red}%
    {red!25}%
    {magenta}%
    {magenta!25}%
    {olive}%
    {olive!25}%
    {brown}%
    {brown!10}%
    {violet}%
    {violet!25}%
    {gray}%
    {purple}%
    {yellow}%
    {orange}%
    {orange!25}%
    {cyan}%
    {green}%
}%

\definecolor{titlecolor1}{rgb}{.9,0.40,0.7}

\newcommand*{\GridSize}{20}

%#2-Gridsizex
%#3-Gridsizey
\newcommand*{\ColorCells}[2]{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#1} {
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomColor}{MyRandomColors}
            \draw [draw=olive!45,fill=\RandomColor, fill opacity=0.2, ultra thick]
                ([shift={(\x-1,\y-1)}]current page.south west) rectangle ++(1cm,1cm);
        }%
    }%
}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\begin{scope}[scale=0.8,ultra thick,olive!45]
    \ColorCells{35}{27}
\end{scope}

\node[rotate=90, above right,text width=26cm,
node font=\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1] at ($(current page.south east)+(.25,1)$)
{Depression Problems and Active Modeling};

\node[rotate=90, above right,text width=26cm,
node font=\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1] at ($(current page.south east)+(-5.5,21)$)
{(Spring 2016)};

\node[above right,
node font=\fontsize{40}{90}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1!20!black] at ($(current page.south west)+(1,1)$)
{Jimmy Jones Jeremy};

\node[blur shadow, anchor=north west] at ($(current page.north west)+(1,-1)$) {\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image}};

\node[blur shadow, text width=10cm, align=left, draw, anchor=south east, fill=white] at ($(current page.south east)+(-6,5)$){ 
Contributor: Dixie Wang\\
Date: February 15th, 2016\\
Filed: February 15th, 2016};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: Colored "minipage"**

Although it was not explicitly asked I've tried to mimic the squared, colorful and shadowed aspect of the so called `minipage`. The best solution I've found was to add some more parameters to `\ColorCells` command and use an empty but shadowed node which will be covered for colored cells and text later on.

[image]
`\Colorcells` has now five parameters, a coordinate for bottom left corner, its horizontal and vertical size (square number), a color list and `fill opacity`:

```
%#1-Origin: bottom left corner
%#2-Gridsizex
%#3-Gridsizey
%#4-ColorList
%#5-Opacity
\newcommand*{\ColorCells}[5]{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#3} {
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomColor}{#4}
            \draw [draw=olive!45,fill=\RandomColor, fill opacity=#5, ultra thick]
                ([shift={(\x-1,\y-1)}]#1) rectangle ++(1cm,1cm);
        }%
    }%
}%
```

Now full page background and colored `minipage` are drawn with commands:

```
\begin{scope}[scale=0.8,ultra thick,olive!45]
    \ColorCells{current page.south west}{27}{35}{MyRandomColors}{0.2}
    \node[blur shadow, fit={($(current page.south west)+(9.2,5.2)$) 
         ($(current page.south west)+(20.2,9.2)$)}, inner sep=0pt] (fitaux) {};
    \coordinate (aux) at ($(current page.south west)+(9.2,5.2)$);
    \ColorCells{aux}{11}{4}{MyRandomColorsTwo}{1}
    \node[align=left, node font=\LARGE, text=white] at (fitaux.center) { 
          Contributor: Dixie Wang\\
          Date: February 15th, 2016\\
          Filed: February 15th, 2016}; 
\end{scope}
```

First `ColorCells` draws page background. Next an empty node is drawn to add the shadow for the colored section which is drawn with second `ColorCells` command and finally, text is added with a regular node. This minipage has been  missplaced from background grid to increase overlay effect.

Complete code for second version:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadows, shadows.blur, fit}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{MyRandomColors}{%
    {red}%
    {red!25}%
    {magenta}%
    {magenta!25}%
    {olive}%
    {olive!25}%
    {brown}%
    {brown!10}%
    {violet}%
    {violet!25}%
    {gray}%
    {purple}%
    {yellow}%
    {orange}%
    {orange!25}%
    {cyan}%
    {green}%
}%

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{MyRandomColorsTwo}{%
    {red!70!black}%
    {magenta!70!black}%
    {olive!70!black}%
    {brown!70!black}%
    {violet!70!black}%
}%

\definecolor{titlecolor1}{rgb}{.9,0.40,0.7}

\newcommand*{\GridSize}{20}

%#1-Origin
%#2-Gridsizex
%#3-Gridsizey
%#4-ColorList
%#5-Opacity
\newcommand*{\ColorCells}[5]{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#3} {
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomColor}{#4}
            \draw [draw=olive!45,fill=\RandomColor, fill opacity=#5, ultra thick]
                ([shift={(\x-1,\y-1)}]#1) rectangle ++(1cm,1cm);
        }%
    }%
}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay
]

\begin{scope}[scale=0.8,ultra thick,olive!45]
    \ColorCells{current page.south west}{27}{35}{MyRandomColors}{0.2}
    \node[blur shadow, fit={($(current page.south west)+(9.2,5.2)$) ($(current page.south west)+(20.2,9.2)$)}, inner sep=0pt] (fitaux) {};
    \coordinate (aux) at ($(current page.south west)+(9.2,5.2)$);
    \ColorCells{aux}{11}{4}{MyRandomColorsTwo}{1}
    \node[align=left, node font=\LARGE, text=white] at (fitaux.center) { 
          Contributor: Dixie Wang\\
          Date: February 15th, 2016\\
          Filed: February 15th, 2016}; 
\end{scope}

\node[rotate=90, above right,text width=26cm,
node font=\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1] at ($(current page.south east)+(.25,1)$)
{Depression Problems and Active Modeling};

\node[rotate=90, above right,text width=26cm,
node font=\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1] at ($(current page.south east)+(-5.5,21)$)
{(Spring 2016)};

\node[above right,
node font=\fontsize{40}{90}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily,
text=titlecolor1!20!black] at ($(current page.south west)+(1,1)$)
{Jimmy Jones Jeremy};

\node[blur shadow, anchor=north west] at ($(current page.north west)+(1,-1)$) {\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```