# How to get figure at the bottom of the coverpage with no margin?

Tags: floats

I found how to spread the image across the width of the page, but I cannot find how to make it start from the bottom.

I used this:

\begin{center}
   \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Images/westworld-004.jpg}}
\end{center}

But my figure is floating in the middle of the page and with \vspace I can force it down, but the margin still shows.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You could try using `\vspace*{\fill}`
before `\begin{center}`. BTW why are you using `\textwidth` and `\paperwidth`? You are making a box with the width of `\textwidth` to include a graphic scaled to `\paperwidth`. Why don't you just use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`?

Comment: The easiest way to fill an entire page is to use tikz.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289067/front-cover-for-document (for example).

Comment: Determine the height of the bottom margin, then insert at the bottom, inside the `minipage`, a negative `\vspace` of that height.